# PySpark - Getting jaccard similarity from co-ocurrence matrix

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a co-occurence matrix in pyspark for co-ocurrences of certain keywords A,B,C

```
    A   B   C
A   5   1   0
B   1   3   2
C   0   2   3
```

How can I calculate the jaccard similarity from this matrix in Python for all keywords. Is there any library available to do that or should I simply compute the similarity by using the Jaccard similarity formula?

Comment: Why do want to use PySpark for this task instead of pure Python (or [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html))? Is your matrix so large that you have to use some kind of parallelism?

Comment: I see you added the [tag:pyspark] tag after I answered. While I am not familiar enough with pyspark to use it in my answer, I expect the approach is the same as what I show with numpy -- Get the values of the diagonal elements, tile it vertically and horizontally, add the two matrices, and then subtract the original matrix from it. This gives you the values of `|A ∪ B|`, then you need to divide the original matrix by this matrix for the Jaccard similarity.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923110/spark-python-how-to-calculate-jaccard-similarity-between-each-line-within-an-rd)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume the co-occurrence matrix is given as a list of lists:

```
com = [[5, 1, 0], 
       [1, 3, 2],
       [0, 2, 3]]
n_elem = len(com)
```

The [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) of two sets `A` and `B` is given by `|A ∩ B| / |A ∪ B|`. The co-occurrence matrix gives the value of `|A|`, `|B|`, and `|A ∩ B|`. The value of `|A ∪ B|` is simply `|A| + |B| - |A ∩ B|`, which we can find the Jaccard index.

First, let's create a list of lists containing ones that is the same size as `com`. The default value is `1` because the similarity index of a set with itself is `1`, and we will not calculate these elements:

```
similarity = [[1 for _ in row] for row in com]
```

Now, we can loop over each pair of values in `com` and calculate the similarities. The inner loop starts at `i+1` because `similarity[i][j]` is identical to `similarity[j][i]`, so we only need to calculate the upper triangle of the matrix:

```
for i in range(n_elem):
    a = com[i][i]               # |A|
    for j in range(i+1, n_elem):
        b = com[j][j]           # |B|
        aib = com[i][j]         # |A ∩ B|
        aub = a + b - aib       # |A ∪ B|
        # Set both off-diagonal elements simultaneously
        similarity[i][j] = similarity[j][i] = aib / aub
```

This leaves us with the following `similarity` matrix:

```
[[1                  , 0.14285714285714285, 0.0], 
 [0.14285714285714285, 1                  , 0.5], 
 [0.0                , 0.5                , 1]]
```

---

Now, if your co-occurrence matrix is a numpy array (or you're open to using numpy), you can speed up this computation by outsourcing the loops to numpy's C backend.

```
import numpy as np
com_arr = np.array([[5, 1, 0], 
       [1, 3, 2],
       [0, 2, 3]])
n_elem = com_arr.size
```

First, we can get the occurrence of each element using the diagonal of the matrix:

```
occ = np.diag(com_arr) # array([5, 3, 3])
```

Next, create the matrix of `|A ∪ B|`. Remember that `|A ∩ B|` is already specified by `com_arr`:

```
aub = occ[:, None] + occ[None, :] - com_arr
```

Since `occ` is a 1-d array, adding a `None` index will create a 2-d array of one column (a column vector of shape `(3, 1)`) and one row (a row vector of shape `(1, 3)`) respectively. When adding a row vector to a column vector, numpy automatically broadcasts the dimensions so that you end up with a (in this case) square matrix of shape `(3, 3)`. Now, `aub` looks like this:

```
array([[5, 7, 8],
       [7, 3, 4],
       [8, 4, 3]])
```

Finally, divide the intersection by the union:

```
similarity = com_arr / aub
```

et voila, we have the same values as before:

```
array([[1.        , 0.14285714, 0.        ],
       [0.14285714, 1.        , 0.5       ],
       [0.        , 0.5       , 1.        ]])
```